# Has SugarWod (iOS) implemented a Custom Url?

Tags: ios

I'm specifically looking to see if SugarWod has implemented a Custom Url, and if so, what it is. They have no developer documentation available and their support has yet to respond back.

If that's unknown, is there a list of sites that currently implement a Custom Url, so that another iOS app can open it?

Or is there a way to see find the Custom Url of an app, if it exists, from your device, iTunes, etc?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It supports a custom URL which starts with sugarwod://

You can easily find this out for any app you have the IPA file of.
1. Rename the extension of the app from .ipa to .zip
2. Extract the zip file
3. Go to the Payload folder of the app
4. Right click on the single file there and choose "show package contents"
5. Open the Info.plist in Xcode and look for the URL types

If there are supported URL's, they can be found there.

Comment: @Dbl0McJim developer of sugarwod here... I replied to your support question yesterday but looks like you already got your answer. Very curious what you're building and integration w/ sugarwod!

Comment: @DrewInTheMountains, I replied to the original support ticket. Thanks.